# Add css to Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: html, css, ajax

I've got a series of `Ajax.ActionLink()` that determine what is displayed on my `Index` page. This is cool and all, but I'd like to determine which one of them is the "active" tab that was clicked by adding my css for active tabs. Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

Here's the code that I have:

```
@if (SecurityHelper.CheckForSecurityRight(SecurityRight.Report_FundrasingSummaryReport)) {
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Test1", "LoadReportConfiguration", new {ReportID = 5},new AjaxOptions {InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ReportConfiguration"})
}


@if (SecurityHelper.CheckForSecurityRight(SecurityRight.Report_CampaignGivingSummary)) {
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Test12", "LoadReportConfiguration", new { ReportID = 8 }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ReportConfiguration" })
}
@if (SecurityHelper.CheckForSecurityRight(SecurityRight.Report_SolicitorAction)) {
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Test13", "LoadReportConfiguration", new { ReportID = 9 }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ReportConfiguration" })
}

@if (SecurityHelper.CheckForSecurityRight(SecurityRight.Report_PortfolioManagement)) {
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Test14", "LoadReportConfiguration", new { ReportID = 10 }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ReportConfiguration" })
}
```

I've tried to add `new {@class="active"} to the end of each`if`, but it showed all of them as active. How can I accomplish only one active at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through Javascript by listening to which link they clicked on and adding the active class to that element.

Add an HTML attribute to each of your links by adding the `new {@class='navigationLink'}` parameter to the @Ajax.ActionLink method.

Using JQuery, you can add the following within a $.ready function.

```
$('.navigationLink').click(function(){
    $('.navigationLink').removeClass('active');  //Remove active class from all other links. 
    $(this).addClass('active');  //Add active class to current link. 
});
```

Here I am using a navigationLink class to mark it as a link in the collection of links. When the user clicks on an HTML element that has a class of navigationLink, it will search for all of the other navigationLinks and remove the active class from each, then add the active class to the current link being clicked on.